# Filter by language only if the object is a literal

Tags: database, rdf, sparql, triplestore

I've written the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ?predicate
  ?object
  ?label
WHERE {
  VALUES        ?subject     { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hercules_(1997_film)> }
  ?subject      ?predicate   ?object .
  ?predicate    rdfs:label   ?label .
  FILTER(langMatches(lang(?object), "EN"))
}
LIMIT 100
```

When I write the `FILTER` line this way, I've essentially filtered out all non-literals (*side question: are literals the only type that can have a language tag?*)

So, how do I keep all of my results and filter out *non-english literals* only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`isLiteral` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-isLiteral) to apply the language restriction only to objects that are literals.

*x implies y* can be expressed with SPARQL operators as *!x || y*, so you could write your query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ?predicate
  ?object
  ?label
WHERE {
  VALUES        ?subject     { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hercules_(1997_film)> }
  ?subject      ?predicate   ?object .
  ?predicate    rdfs:label   ?label .
  FILTER(!isLiteral(?object) || langMatches(lang(?object), "EN"))
}
LIMIT 100
```

As for your secondary question, the [description for language tags from the RDF concepts and abstracts](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-concepts-20040210/#dfn-language-identifier) only mentions language tags to appear as a part of *plain literals*. Likewise, the [grammar in the SPARQL 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#sparqlGrammar) uses the [`LANGTAG` nonterminal](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rLANGTAG) only in the [`RDFLiteral` production](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rRDFLiteral) as an exclusive alternative instead of a datatype IRI.

Comment: In general, this works, though I did end up adding a second line of `FILTER`: one line pertaining to `?object` and another pertaining to `?label`.

Comment: @Kristian: You may want to consider the [`OPTIONAL` keyword](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#OptionalMatching) for checking anything related to the label, as in some datasets, not all resources are provided with a label.