# Filter language only if the type is literal

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

This is probably almost the same quetion as:
[Filter by language only if the object is a literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685776/filter-by-language-only-if-the-object-is-a-literal)

Problem is that the answer there doesn't work in my case.

I have this query:

```
SELECT ?property ?value
WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Facebook> ?property ?value
FILTER(STRSTARTS(STR(?property), "http://dbpedia.org/property") || STRSTARTS(STR(?property), "http://dbpedia.org/ontology"))}
```

[Result in Virtuoso](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++++++SELECT+%3Fproperty+%3Fvalue%0D%0A++++++++WHERE+%7B+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FFacebook%3E+%3Fproperty+%3Fvalue%0D%0A++++++++FILTER%28STRSTARTS%28STR%28%3Fproperty%29%2C+%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%22%29+%7C%7C+STRSTARTS%28STR%28%3Fproperty%29%2C+%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%22%29%29%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

There you would see a list of properties including "alexa rating 2" and "abstract" in many languages.

If I then try the suggested solution in the mentioned question above:

```
SELECT ?property ?value
WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Facebook> ?property ?value
FILTER(STRSTARTS(STR(?property), "http://dbpedia.org/property") || STRSTARTS(STR(?property), "http://dbpedia.org/ontology"))
FILTER(!isLiteral(?value) || langMatches(lang(?value), "EN"))}
```

[Result in Virtuoso](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++++++SELECT+%3Fproperty+%3Fvalue%0D%0A++++++++WHERE+%7B+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FFacebook%3E+%3Fproperty+%3Fvalue%0D%0A++++++++FILTER%28STRSTARTS%28STR%28%3Fproperty%29%2C+%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%22%29+%7C%7C+STRSTARTS%28STR%28%3Fproperty%29%2C+%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%22%29%29%0D%0A++++++++FILTER%28%21isLiteral%28%3Fvalue%29+%7C%7C+langMatches%28lang%28%3Fvalue%29%2C+%22EN%22%29%29%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Now you would see that only english version of "abstract" is there but "alexa rating 2" and many other non-string values are gone.

Anyone that knows how to get all properties as in the first query and then for literals only filter out the english language?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your second query *does* filter out literals that have a language tag other than English.  In RDF 1.0, there are three types of literals:

- plain literals (no datatype, and no language tag)
- language tagged literals (a string and a language tag)
- datatype literals (a lexical form and a datatype)

So the Alexa rating, which has a value of `2`, *is* a literal, and it doesn't have a language tag, so the language tag certainly isn't `"EN"` (and more importantly, doesn't *match* `"EN"`;  langMatches does some more complex checks).  What you want is to filter out non-English language tagged literals.  That's not hard;  you just need to add `lang(?value) = ""` to the filter (since lang returns "" for literals with no language tag):

```
SELECT ?property ?value
WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Facebook> ?property ?value
FILTER(STRSTARTS(STR(?property), "http://dbpedia.org/property") || STRSTARTS(STR(?property), "http://dbpedia.org/ontology"))
FILTER(!isLiteral(?value) || lang(?value) = "" || langMatches(lang(?value), "EN"))}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fvalue%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FFacebook%3E%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fvalue%0D%0AFILTER%28STRSTARTS%28STR%28%3Fproperty%29%2C%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%22%29%20%7C%7C%20STRSTARTS%28STR%28%3Fproperty%29%2C%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%22%29%29%0D%0AFILTER%28%21isLiteral%28%3Fvalue%29%20%7C%7C%20lang%28%3Fvalue%29%20%3D%20%22%22%20%7C%7C%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fvalue%29%2C%20%22EN%22%29%29%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

The way to read that filter is:

> Keep values that
>
> 1. are not literals; *or*
> 2. are literals, but don't have a language tag; *or*
> 3. are literals with a language tag that matches "en".

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you simply want to invert the filter condition on the language right?

In which case you simply need to invert the `langMatches` call by adding a `!` before it i.e. adding the not operator to it:

```
SELECT ?property ?value
WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Facebook> ?property ?value
FILTER(STRSTARTS(STR(?property), "http://dbpedia.org/property") || STRSTARTS(STR(?property), "http://dbpedia.org/ontology"))
FILTER(!isLiteral(?value) || !langMatches(lang(?value), "EN"))}
```

[Result in DBPedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%3Fproperty+%3Fvalue%0D%0A++++WHERE+%7B+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FFacebook%3E+%3Fproperty+%3Fvalue%0D%0A++++FILTER%28STRSTARTS%28STR%28%3Fproperty%29%2C+%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%22%29+%7C%7C+STRSTARTS%28STR%28%3Fproperty%29%2C+%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%22%29%29%0D%0A++++FILTER%28%21isLiteral%28%3Fvalue%29+%7C%7C+%21langMatches%28lang%28%3Fvalue%29%2C+%22EN%22%29%29%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

With this simple change the English entries are now eliminated and I see only the non-English entries.

Comment: I don't think this is right.  I think OP wants to keep all the literals that have no language tag, and keep only those language tagged literals whose languages match "en".